# "libcontainerd: failed to receive event from containerd: rpc error: code = 13 desc = transport is closing"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, datastore, dataflow

We are suffering this error in our Dataflow job for three or four months:

> libcontainerd: failed to receive event from containerd: rpc error: code = 13 desc = transport is closing

My notions about Dataflow are quite limited, but it seems to be a correlation between the appearance of this error and a sudden decay of the CPU activity of our worker.

I have been reading a bit about it in different entries and at first I thought it had to do with the google.cloud.datastore library (we make a lot of queries and write a great number of entities in our datastore database) , but I am not sure at all right now. Do you have any idea concerning this error? If you do, any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to reaching the machine resources limits, you should try using a [higher machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#general_purpose) . You can specify the machine type within the Pipeline configuration [options](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-pipeline-options)

There is a similar issue reported on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/113347184)